# How to use SIM800's AT+HTTPHEAD

Tags: http, at-command, modem

I want to set the Real Time Clock on my STM32F4 board that I use with a SIM800 modem. I try to send HTTP GET or HEAD request (for example to "google.com") and use the timestamp in the response header to set my RTC.

I can send the request and get the response but I can't read the response's header.

The code is use and the response:

```
AT+HTTPINIT
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
OK

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","www.google.com"
OK

AT+HTTPACTION=0
OK
+HTTPACTION: 0,302,256

AT+HTTPHEAD
ERROR
```

Why I got the ERROR at the end? I tried to send request to another URL, in this case I get HTTP OK(200) and can read data but still can't the header.

Comment: I couldn't solve this problem, but found another way. I used AT+CIPSTART and after I send an HTTP HEAD request.

Comment: Kindly elaborate.

I am having a similar issue. I am calling a post method, restful webservice. Wherein I have to pass two parameters  in header, `AT+HTTPPARA="CONTENT","application/json"` and "AuthenticationToke=myAuthorizationKeyToken".

I am not able to pass two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AT+HTTPHEAD doesn't work in sim800C. It works in: SIM800H,SIM800L,SIM800,SIM800G. Read "AT Command Manual" -

> Only Part of Projects Support Following AT Commands.

Answer (score 0):

+HTTPACTION: 0,302,256,
302 error is **Found**.
Check **Mobile Balance** or **Internet Package** in your sim.
It happens when you are out of **Balance**.